Why does it satisfy the definition of a subgradient vector in a flow network problem

Hello everyone, I need to clarify some doubts. I was reading the article 'Subgradient Optimization Methods in Integer Programming with an Application to a Radiation Therapy Problem.' This is my first time encountering the topic of graphs, and in this case, they use the Hamacher Boland model. They associate an intensity matrix I
with a matrix, which is linked to a Lagrangian relaxation. In one part of the definition, to find the segmented matrices, they use the subgradient method, where the subgradient vector is defined as shown in the image. My question is about how to interpret this definition of the subgradient vector and how it would satisfy the definition of a subgradient. If anyone has any bibliography or could perhaps explain the interpretation, I would greatly appreciate it.
